# Facebook FQL Query Order By Using Multiple Columns

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have a Facebook FQL query which in which everything is going good but what I want is to Order the results by 2 columns.

Here is the last line of the script and until this it is working.

```
IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=133025843429181)ORDER BY created desc
```

What I want is to order it by created desc and like_info desc, so this is what I am trying and it returns an error.

```
IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=133025843429181)ORDER BY created desc, like_info desc
```

This is not working. I tried to remove the comma in between and still not working

```
IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=133025843429181)ORDER BY created desc like_info desc
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#601) Parser error: unexpected 'ASC' at position 142.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 601
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code: It might be the fix you need

```
IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=133025843429181) ORDER BY (created desc * like_info desc) DESC
```

Comment: This is getting me an error and not fixing the situation. This is the error which I get

{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#601) Parser error: unexpected 'ASC' at position 142.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 601
  }
}

Comment: I don't see any ASC in the script and I don't know why it is giving this error. I am running this query for testing in graph api explorer with API Version 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible.

> FQL can handle simple math, basic boolean operators, AND or NOT logical operators, and ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses. ORDER BY can contain only a single table.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql#query